# Firebase realtime database with google authentication in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-oauth

The Firebase database denies access when I want to perform writes or reads.

I have already tried logging in with a google account and writing to the database. I don't know why the database does not allow writing or reading. Maybe I'm doing the authentication wrong or my firebase login is wrong?

Here is the code with which I log in to the Google account

```
function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  const onGoogleButtonPress = async () => {
    // Check if your device supports Google Play
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
    // Get the users ID token
    const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
  
    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    const user_sign_in = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    user_sign_in.then((user) => {
      console.log(user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

I wanted to write to the database with this code, but I got a permission denied error

```
const writeDataToDatabase = (data) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.idToken);
      set(ref(db, user.uid), data)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Successful');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error: ', error);
        });
    }
  };
```

This is the Firebase rules

```
"rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
```